# Using JQuery auto complete with php/mysql not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I am trying to use a code that was flagged as working and I am not getting any results, it's just empty. Notes: The MySQL does return results if run alone, so it's not an sql thing. Any suggestions?

**HTML:**

```
<head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">       
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        Name: <input id="hint" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $("#hint").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "getMedicineNames.php",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        data: {
                            name: request
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 3
            });

        </script>
    </body>
```

**PHP:**

```
require 'connect.inc.php';
$mysql = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass", "$db_name");
$name = $_POST['name'];
if ($name != "") {

    $sql = "SELECT MedicineName FROM medicinetypes WHERE MedicineNAme LIKE '%$name%'";
    echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($mysql, $sql), MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}
```

Comment: correct this line `dataType: "json", ` not the `dataType: "jsonp",`

Comment: also include `type : "POST",`

Comment: still nothing..

Comment: can you add your response of ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found a better answer, but the main problem was my php code where I left the array as an assoc which is wrong.

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#hint").autocomplete({
        source: 'getMedicineNames.php'
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$mysql = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass", "$db_name");
$name = $_GET['term'];

$sql = "SELECT MedicineName FROM medicinetypes WHERE MedicineNAme LIKE '%$name%'";
$res = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);
$res = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($res as $row){
    $data[]=$row['MedicineName'];

}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add dataType: "json", & type : "GET".

If not working please add your screenshot of JSON response.

Comment: ok so changed a few thing, first it's request.term then and php now accepts get. The data is successfuly returned and shown on the console with console.log(data) but it stops there, there is nothing happening on the front-end

Comment: now i made something happen but some empty tiny fields appear

Answer (score 0):

Bilal Ahmed answer is correct.

Aditinoally this is a bit incorrect:

```
$name = $_POST['name']; // Maybe cause a PHP Warning
```

You can solve this creating a unset value:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
/* "" can be NULL, FALSE, 0 or any value */
```

In PHP7 you can make this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? "";
/* "" can be NULL, FALSE, 0 or any value */
```